# How do I add attibution links to 'teaser thumbnails' in Drupal blog posts?

Tags: media, nodes

I'm running a professional blog on, I believe, Drupal 6.17. It allows me to include a 'teaser thumbnail' of an image with each blog post. However, many times I want to use free stock photos from sites such as flickr and freedigitalphotos.net as that teaser. However, these sites require you to include a link back to the photographer's page along with an attritbution on the same page as the photo. I'm not sure how to do that with Drupal's 'teaser thumbnail' option.

Answer (score 1):

For D6, use the [ImageField Extended](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_extended) module. It provides a very simple admin interface to give you a way of adding textfields, textareas, WYSIWYG textareas and checkboxes.